# How can i set the print interval in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

How can I set the print interval for different artboards?

An example:

I have 25 artboards, I need to print 2 copies of the first, 3 copies of the last and 5 copies for each other. How do I set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** easy way to do this! While it is possible to insert pages to print a comma separated list of pages in the range textbox. So in this hypothetical case you could type:

```
1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,  ... 24,24,24,24,24, 25,25,25
```

Where you would fill in the ... with all your pages. Unfortunately, this will not work for the page range you suggested as there is a 256 character limit in the field. However you can try instead:

```
1,1, 2-24,2-24,2-24,2-24,2-24, 25,25,25
```

But this may or may not have the collation order you want. Unfortunately the adobe publishing suite is not a print management hub.

You could write a script to do this but that would mean you would have many print jobs. In certain cases that might not be ideal like for example if you were to collate a PDF you'd just get many files. Though if you have acrobat or say ghostScript it might be easier to do there.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time print need, just print manually.

But, if you need to do this repeatedly, or even send the file to other people so that it prints as specified for other users, you can MAKE OVERLAPPING ARTBOARDS. For the first page make another artboard right on top of the existing one. For the last page, make two duplicates. For all other artboards, make four duplicates.

You can make those new artboards very quickly by making a new layer (for convenience of selection), creating rectangles (unrotated!) where you want the new artboards, and then selecting all rectangles on the layer and using the CONVERT TO ARTBOARDS command.

(If you need to get really clever, you will have a layer of rectangles for your single/original artboards, and another for your print-duplicate artboards, so if you need to change the 2,5,5,5,5...3 print spec, you can quickly delete all existing artboards and then quickly create new ones from the rectangles. Remember, though, that the Convert To Artboards command consumes the rectangles, so copy & paste-in-place first, then convert to artboards, leaving your original rectangles for future need.)